# On drawing a large number of lines in the OnPaint method results in Unresponsive state

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, onpaint

In my custom control am using nearly 1000 series with 100 points each which results in delay in drawing and even after drawn also it takes some amount time to be responsive.

Am even using Begin and End update before loading points. But no use.

I have replicated the same in a simple sample by drawing a line in a loop, which also goes to unresponsive state.

Is there any solution to overcome this.

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ControlExt controlExt = new ControlExt();
        this.Controls.Add(controlExt);
    }

  public class ControlExt : Control
  {

    public ControlExt()
    {
        Height = 500;
        Width = 1000;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 400, 200, 300, 100);
                }
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: a) doublebuffering the control makes a huge difference here (between unresponsive and just a little lag, here) b) make sure those lines are really needed (how large are your controls and your screen really?) if they don't change very often, create a bitmap!

Comment: Yes, this double buffering works in the code I have shared. But in my application even on using this, it takes much time to respond, since OnPaint method is calling nearly 4 times, drawing completed on the first call itself  and my app taking the time to complete the remaining 3 times call of OnPaint and this results in delay after drawn.

Comment: _OnPaint method is calling nearly 4 times_ Why is it called so often?

Comment: Yeah I was checking on the same. How to get rid of this or how to find out why it is being called that much time? Might be I have done some mistake...but how to find out the exact reason of paint calling.

Comment: Paint is called by the system whenever the old layout changes. So if you have a series of those changes it is recommended to set a flag to abort Paint until it is reset (or use the Suspend/ResumeLayout calls where they exist). Typical layout changes are resizing the control or one of its child controls, changing content, selecting items etc.. Another case is moving the window out of and back into the screen area.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing lines is done on the main thread, and can be quite inefficient when there is many lines. Winforms is based on GDI, and this uses [Immediate Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics)) rendering. This has a tendency to scale poorly since the processor have to send all the commands to the graphics device each frame.

The typical solution is to use fewer drawing commands, and therefore suffer less overhead. For example:

- Use [DrawLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawlines?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) if the line segments are connected in strips.
- Create a graphics path for all the lines and use [DrawPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawpath?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)
- Create a Bitmap, draw to this image on a background thread, and then use [DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) in the UI.